# Filtering a CSV File using two columns

Tags: python

I am a newbie to python. I am working on a `CSV` file where it has over a million records. In the data, every **Location** has a unique ID (**SiteID**). I want to filter for and remove any records where there is **no value or mismatch between `SiteID` and `Location`** in my `CSV` file. (Note: This script should print the lines number and mismatch field values for each record.)

I have the following code. Please help me out:

```
import pandas as pd

pd = pandas.read_csv ('car-auction-data-from-ghana', delimiter = ";")
pd.head()

date_time = (pd['Date Time'] >= '2010-01-01T00:00:00+00:00') #to filter from a specific date 

comparison_column = pd.where(pd['SiteID'] == pd['Location'], True, False)

comparison_column
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be your solution:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('car-auction-data-from-ghana', delimiter = ";")    
print(df.head())    
    
date_time = (df['Date Time'] >= '2010-01-01T00:00:00+00:00') #to filter from a specific date    
    
df = df[df['SiteID'] == df['Location']]
print(df)
```

You need to call read_csv as a member of pd because it is the alias to the imported package, and use df as the variable for your data frame. The line with the comparison drops rows in which the boolean is not equal, the two not being equal in this case.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. The code works however it returns 23 columns and the 0 rows. From the professor, it should return over 700,000 rows of data.